# java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Всем привет. Помогите пожалуйста. Может кто-то с этим сталкивался.
Как побороть `java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response`?
Пишу приложение на Java, Spring, в jsp использую тэги в т.ч. jstl
создаю ajax запрос со страницы jsp к контроллеру, в контроллере вылетает это исключение когда вызываю getOutputStream:

```java
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/getimg", produces = "image/png")
public String getImage (HttpServletResponse response, @RequestParam("id") int idImg)
{
    OutputStream outputStream = null;
    try {
        outputStream = response.getOutputStream(); <-Исключение!!!
        ....
    } catch (IOException exception){
        ...
    } 
    return "page";
}
```

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:549)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:465)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:605)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:544)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:461)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:201)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getWriter(Response.java:638)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getWriter(ResponseFacade.java:214)
    at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getWriter(ServletResponseWrapper.java:105)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.initOut(JspWriterImpl.java:125)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.flushBuffer(JspWriterImpl.java:118)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.release(PageContextImpl.java:182)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.internalReleasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:126)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.releasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:80)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.errorPage_jsp._jspService(errorPage_jsp.java:89)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
```

Comment: а зачем вам читать Response?

Comment: мне нужен текущий поток записи, чтобы записать в него Bufferedimage -> она отобразилась на странице

Comment: response.getOutputStream() я и беру текущий поток

Comment: и я не знаю как по-другому передать эту картинку

Comment: а вы точно 2 раза не вызываете getOutputStream()?

Comment: сам вручную нет, судя по всему JSPWriter виноват. Так как если пишу getWriter то ошибки нет и в trace есть строка at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getWriter(Response.java:638). Но как это фиксить я не знаю, уже все перерыл

Comment: response.getWriter().write(bufferedImage), попробуйте так?

Comment: писал, тогда картинка не выводится. И переводил Writer в outputstream - та же фигня

Comment: с response.getOutputStream(); картинку рисует но вылетает это исключение

Comment: public @ResponseBody byte[] getImageAsByteArray() throws IOException {
    return IOUtils.toByteArray(bufferedImage);
}

Comment: я не писал content type. нужно писать в методе content type? у меня spring controllerы

Comment: не, вы его написали в produces

Comment: 1) не принимает на вход BufferedImage этот метод
2) я уже пробовал массив байтов:

Comment: ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ImageIO.write(service.createQR(), "PNG", output);
            model.addAttribute("image", output.toByteArray());

Comment: и картинка не выводилась, может я ее неправильно выводил конечно. Как вывести ее на страницу из массива байтов?

Comment: ну попробуйте для начала сохранить как файл, если получится открыть, то смотрите на клиентской стороне

Comment: в любом случае спасибо

Comment: перефразируйте вопрос, может тогда помогут

Comment: если вы используете jsp, то нельзя открывать выходной поток вручную, т. к. он уже открыт. response.getOutputStream() уберите. Нужно переделывать контроллер, как приводил пример Komdosh